# Using the \getpwd command to recover the current directory where this command was used

Tags: currfile

Does \getpwd command work only with "pdflatex --recorder file.tex" compiling process? I am using the DVI -> PS -> PDF chain to compile in TeXstudio 2.12.6 and the \getpwd is returning empty text.

Follow the Minimum Work Exemple (MWE) that I want compile using the DVI -> PS -> PDF chain:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}

\begin{document}

   dir: \getpwd

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, the `-recorder` option is necessary. Can you make a small example of how you use `\getpwd`?

Comment: With `\getpwd` you just define `\thepwd`; if you want to print (or use for other purposes)  the name of the directory, with its path, you have to use `\thepwd`.

Comment: I updated the question above with MWE as requested.

Comment: I have a tree of subdirectories that I want to concatenate with \getpwd. Exemple: for an "equation" subdirectory, I would want something as \input(\getpwd\equation).

Comment: Sorry, but this is quite unclear.

Comment: The idea is get the current path of directory of the file where the command `\getpwd` is being used, and associate with other files that they are into the directories in same root directory (of that file which has the `\getpwd` being used). Thus I would access by `\input` command. 

I want to make it, because I want beware to move the file with the same root directory without edit the `\input` command every time.