# currfile does not show file path

Tags: currfile

I tried to use the currfile package to print the name + path of the source file. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{currfile}
\begin{document}
 Filename: \currfilename

 Path:  \currfiledir
\end{document}
```

The latex output gives the filename but does not show the path.  There was no error message when I latexed the file, nor do I see any error message in the .log so I'm at a lost of what to do.  Thanks for your help!

In case this matters:  I use texlive 2017/debian, and at least in the near future I would not be able to update the texlive  setup.

Comment: did you use the recorder option to pdflatex? see section 4 of the currfile manual

Comment: @Carlisle:  I did but it didn't work.  Instead I followed  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416886/using-the-getpwd-command-to-recover-the-current-directory-where-this-command-wa  and  use  \usepackage[abspath]{currfile}  and then  \thepwd  gives the absolute path.